# Testcontainers error with image couchbase:enterprise-7.1.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, testcontainers

Hello I am having some issue starting this image (couchbase:enterprise-7.1.4), using Testcontainers. This is the way I start the container:

```
 private static final DockerImageName COUCHBASE_IMAGE_ENTERPRISE = DockerImageName
            .parse("couchbase:enterprise-7.1.4")
            .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("couchbase/server");

@Container
    private static final CouchbaseContainer container = new CouchbaseContainer(COUCHBASE_IMAGE_ENTERPRISE)
            .withCredentials("Administrator", "password")
            .withBucket(new BucketDefinition(BUCKET_NAME).withPrimaryIndex(true).withFlushEnabled(true))
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2));
```

This is the error that I experience randomly.

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed for image couchbase:enterprise-7.1.4

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:349)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:274)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:261)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$3(TestcontainersExtension.java:76)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$startContainers$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:76)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.startContainers(TestcontainersExtension.java:76)
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:553)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not perform request against couchbase HTTP endpoint 
    at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.doHttpRequest(CouchbaseContainer.java:790)
    at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.renameNode(CouchbaseContainer.java:400)
    at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.timePhase(CouchbaseContainer.java:802)
    at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.containerIsStarting(CouchbaseContainer.java:341)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.containerIsStarting(GenericContainer.java:703)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:479)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:54155/...
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:202)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.doHttpRequest(CouchbaseContainer.java:788)
    ... 65 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:54155/...
        ... 80 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:332)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
        ... 79 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:54155/...
        ... 80 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:332)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:332)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
    ... 79 more
```

Has anyone experienced such issue?

Here you can find the full code: https://github.com/RosarioB/spring-boot-rest-api-couchbase-crud/tree/basic_crud The test class is CustomerRepositoryTest.

I have tried to use various methods on the container but with little success.

Comment: there are tests running with `couchbase/server:enterprise-7.0.3` but no `couchbase:enterprise-7.1.4`. IIRC those are different somehow

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/6938

Try the work-around of .withStartupAttempts(3)

I made a fix, but that is waiting on approval.

Comment: What fix are you thinking of? Can you please add a link if possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/7049

Here's the pull request.  Retry the rename for up to 60 seconds